# curl from list of URLs: curl splits out the line as arguments

Tags: bash, shell, curl, escaping, quoting

I have this bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
  curl $LINE
  echo " $LINE"
done < $1
```

and the URLs are like this:

```
-v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id": 1, "method": "something", "params": ["en", "1", "bob", "password"]}' https://HTTPAUTHUSER:HTTPAUTHPASS@someurl.com
```

But it seems like curl is getting

```
[11:35]:sh loop.sh tmp.txt
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: application
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
* Rebuilt URL to: 1,/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: 1,
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1,
* Rebuilt URL to: "method":/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: "method"
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "method"
* Rebuilt URL to: "something",/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: "something",
* Closing connection 3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "something",
* Rebuilt URL to: "params":/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious. Any thoughts?

EDIT:

from comments below I added set -x and I see this

```
curl 'MYARGS'
```

when i have

```
curl "$LINE"
```

remove the quotes -> `curl $LINE`

change the curl command like this:

```
curl -v -X POST -H '"Content-Type:' 'application/json"' -d ''\''{"id":' 1, '"method":' '"something",' '"params":' '["en",' '"1",' '"bob",' '"password"]}'\''' https://HTTPAUTHUSER:HTTPAUTHPASS@someurl.com
```

Comment: `curl "$LINE"`? Is that the full code? How are you passing in that line? Via STDIN or a file?

Comment: stdin : ./curl.sh urls.txt

Comment: @cbrulak What is the result of `echo " $LINE"`? Try adding `set -x` at the top of the script.

Comment: Try the quotes around `$LINE` then as in my previous comment. Also use `while read -r LINE`

Comment: @Biffen echo $LINE prints out the URL as expected. set -x after the #/bin/bash didn't change

Comment: @cbrulak *Just* the URL? `set -x` wasn't supposed to *fix* anything, it's just so that you can tell what's going on.

Comment: You *cannot* stuff complicated quoted strings into a string and then splat them on the command line and expect it to work. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050. You need to change your approach here.

Comment: Thanks everyone, clear what's going on.

Comment: maybe ./curl.sh < urls.txt

Comment: @EtanReisner you should put an answer like this so I can accept it.

Comment: The problem is it isn't a direct answer and if you search for BashFAQ/50 on this site you'll see that this sort of thing comes up a lot. A canonical answer for this would be good but I don't know that one exists.